# Compare installed rpm packages with available?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, rpm

I would like to find the vmware packages that I haven't installed from their repo.

The problem is that the output of `yum search vmware` is not the same format at from `rpm -qa|grep vmware`.

**Question**

How Can I make a diff of the installed and available rpm packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `repoquery`. It is in the `yum-utils` package.

```
repoquery 'vmware*'
```

shows all available packages named beginning with `vmware`.

```
repoquery --pkgnarrow=installed 'vmware*'
```

shows *installed* packages named beginning with `vmware`.

It is trivial to then compare the output of these commands.

Answer (score 1):

To get the package format the same, you can simply pass a format specifier to `rpm`. Example: `rpm -qa --queryformat "${NAME}-${ARCH}\n" | grep vmware`. To get to your end goal, I would run that through `sort` and save it to a file, then save `yum search vmware | awk -F: '{print $1}'` to another file and run `diff` against them. There are probably other (better) ways of running that `awk` command, as well.

Comment: Ok, so the `awk` against `yum search` isn't working as well as I expected on my system... this will get you started, but probably won't get you where you need to be.